# Android Studio can't find resource and resource linking failed

Tags: java, android, linker, android-resources, aapt2

Recently I had problems with AAPT2. The problems were caused by my username that contained non-ascii characters. I created another Windows account(without non-ascii characters) and installed Android Studio on it. Then I opened my older project and when AS asked me to update I agreed to that. Now when I try to build my app I get these errors:

> Android resource linking failed
>   D:\Android_Studio\Praca\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values-v28\values-v28.xml:7: error: resource android:attr/dialogCornerRadius not found.
>   D:\Android_Studio\Praca\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values-v28\values-v28.xml:11: error: resource android:attr/dialogCornerRadius not found.
>   D:\Android_Studio\Praca\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:2970: error: resource android:attr/fontVariationSettings not found.
>   D:\Android_Studio\Praca\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:2971: error: resource android:attr/ttcIndex not found.
>   error: failed linking references.

Most of threads I found of StackOverflow suggest that this problem might be related to support library, they say that version of it might be wrong. How could I change the version? My project also uses OpenCV library and configuration of it might be invalid.
What I tried already was cleaning and rebuilding project and adjusting *compileSDKVersion* in Gradle.

Here is *values-v28.xml* file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<style name="Base.Theme.AppCompat" parent="Base.V28.Theme.AppCompat"/>
<style name="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light" parent="Base.V28.Theme.AppCompat.Light"/>
<style name="Base.V28.Theme.AppCompat" parent="Base.V26.Theme.AppCompat">
    <!-- We can use the platform styles on API 28+ -->
    <item name="dialogCornerRadius">?android:attr/dialogCornerRadius</item>
</style>
<style name="Base.V28.Theme.AppCompat.Light" parent="Base.V26.Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <!-- We can use the platform styles on API 28+ -->
    <item name="dialogCornerRadius">?android:attr/dialogCornerRadius</item>
</style>
```

And here is Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.kawa.praca">

<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera"
    android:required="true" />

<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
    android:maxSdkVersion="18" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".Powitanie">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".Trening" />
    <activity android:name=".Zdjecia" />

    <provider
        android:name=".DbProvider"
        android:authorities="com.example.kawa.praca"
        android:exported="true" />
    <provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="com.example.android.fileprovider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
    </provider>

    <activity android:name=".AddActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".UserPanel" />
    <activity android:name=".ScoringPanel" />
    <activity android:name=".Scoring" />
    <activity android:name=".NewPlanActivity" />

    <receiver
        android:name=".PlanReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true" />

    <activity android:name=".ChartsActivity"></activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Also below is my build.gradle file app module. In this file in sub-clause 'dependencies' entries with support library are underlined and AS shows me a warning:

> All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). Found versions 28.0.0, 26.1.0. Examples include com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:28.0.0 and com.android.support:customtabs:26.1.0

I tried changing versions to newer or older but this warning still appears.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 26
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.kawa.praca"
    minSdkVersion 24
    targetSdkVersion 26

    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner 
 "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
sourceSets { main { jni.srcDirs = ['src/main/jni', 'src/main/jniLibs/'] } 
}
// Encapsulates your external native build configurations.
externalNativeBuild {

    // Encapsulates your CMake build configurations.
    cmake {

        // Provides a relative path to your CMake build script.
        path "../CMakeLists.txt"
    }
}
//buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'
productFlavors {
}
}

repositories {
maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
}

dependencies {
//implementation 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.1.0-alpha'
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
implementation 'com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:customtabs:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso- 
core:3.0.1'
implementation project(':openCVLibrary340')
//implementation 'com.jjoe64:graphview:4.2.2'
}

dependencies {
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:+'
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same error fixed it by updating the compilesdkversion to 28, since currently my build tools version is 28.0.3 , hence the version should be same as to have a perfect build.
Also check for your  implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0' 
Change the respective Dependency versions to 28, it will prevent run time crashing